# Table of Contents numbers (but not hyperlinks?) go off-track

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex

I’m creating a book in lualatex, and I’m finding that after a few chapters the Table of Contents page numbers are one more than the actual page of the chapter/section they reference. After another chapter the page numbers are off by two.

Curiously, this doesn’t affect the hyperlinks in the PDF: those always go to the correct place in the PDF.

Is this a familiar problem? Does anyone have ideas for how I could investigate what’s going on besides building the book over and over to narrow down the problem? (Each build of the PDF takes about 30 minutes, so if I could avoid that it would be ideal.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you run latex enough times for the numbers to stabilise? Being out for the first couple of runs is expected.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you! That worked.